# Swap without temp var, warning error, why?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, swap

warning: operation on ‘left’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point] right = right + left - (left = right);

```
{
    int right = 5, left = 14;
    std::cout << right << " " << left << std::endl;
    right = right + left - (left = right);
    std::cout << right << " " << left << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: And such code is used in practice or not?

Comment: It does not compile? Why would it be used? To save a word?

Comment: Related: [How to swap two numbers without using a temporary variable?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-two-numbers-without-using-temporary-variable/)

Comment: I have not seen this technique in embedded systems nor platform applications.  The swap algorithms I've encountered either use a temporary variable/object or use a processor instruction for swapping.  I would say that such code is not used in the real world.